# Plugin Update from Python 2 to 3, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am currently working on an update for an old Plugin which I want to use in QGIS 3. I came across the problem, that when trying to import modules in the same directory of the plugin.py errors occure. so I tried to import the resources.py to the mainplugin.py

I tried
`from . import resources`    --> attempted relative import with no known parent package
`from .resources import *`    --> attempted relative import with no known parent package
`import resouces`   --> No module named 'resources'
I am really confused, because actually this is also what the pygis cookbook says

[image]

Any Ideas what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the system was confused and was not able to find the files. I added the root name instead of the '`.`' then it worked:

```
from root_directory import resources
```